# Chart.js tooltips callback function with pie charts

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

In a chart options configurations I can make my own label.
This is for a bar chart:

```
tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem) {
          var label = tooltipItem.yLabel;
          return  'Scans : ' + label;
        }
      }
    }
```

But for a pie chart all the tooltipItems are empty or 0 values.
What argument can i use to get only the value of where i am hovering in my pie chart? (The value of that specific slice)

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
tooltips: {
    mode: 'label',
    callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) { 
            var indice = tooltipItem.index;                 
            return  data.labels[indice] +': '+data.datasets[0].data[indice] + '';
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that it will be `var indice = tooltipItem[0].index;` if you are stacking data with `stack` option in yours `datasets` array.

Comment: Thanks dude... save me a lot!